# Given two point's latitude and longitude, computing coordinates of point in between

Tags: google-maps, math, maps, mapping, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to generate some annotations on a map. Currently, I'm using openstreetmap but the query is general. I have two end points on a map and a corpus of few selected points I would like to highlight.

The two endpoints are given in the form lat, long

```
<walkSteps>
<distance>9.742464221826811</distance>
<streetName>5th St NW</streetName>
<absoluteDirection>EAST</absoluteDirection>
<stayOn>false</stayOn>
<bogusName>false</bogusName>
<lon>-84.3937361115149</lon>
<lat>33.77692965678444</lat>
<elevation/>
</walkSteps>

<walkSteps>
<distance>508.2608917548245</distance>
<relativeDirection>LEFT</relativeDirection>
<streetName>Fowler St NW</streetName>
<absoluteDirection>NORTH</absoluteDirection>
<stayOn>false</stayOn>
<bogusName>false</bogusName>
<lon>-84.39363494600667</lon>
<lat>33.77692904176358</lat>
<elevation/>
</walkSteps>
```

My aim is to highlight those points on the map, which are present in the corpus and lie in the line connecting these two points.

How can I go about querying the corpus for the same? Annotating on map given lat, lng is not an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounding errors will prevent you from directly doing as you want.  What you should be doing instead is determining the great-circle path between the two end points and highlighting those members of the corpus which are within a certain distance of the great circle route.  This is known as the cross-track distance or cross-track error.  Formulas for computing the cross-track distance can be found at one of the [standard reference sites for geospatial equations](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) but there are [others](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cross%20track%20distance) as well..  The problem then becomes one of searching for points in the corpus which are close enough to the great circle path between the two end points.